# calabash-android build in Mac giving [Error]Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed

Tags: xamarin, calabash, calabash-android, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying to build calabash-android in my mac i am getting the following error

```
sudo calabash-android build /Users/igate/Downloads/SimpleCreditCardValidator/app/app-release.apk
ERROR: Could not find an Android SDK please make sure it is installed.
ERROR: You can read about how Calabash is searching for an Android SDK and how you can help here:
ERROR: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:114:in `setup': Could not find an Android SDK (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:41:in `java_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/dependencies.rb:81:in `keytool_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:186:in `block (2 levels) in fingerprint_from_apk'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:169:in `chdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:169:in `block in fingerprint_from_apk'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tmpdir.rb:88:in `mktmpdir'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/lib/calabash-android/helpers.rb:168:in `fingerprint_from_apk'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:2:in `calabash_build'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/calabash-android-0.8.0/bin/calabash-android:71:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/calabash-android:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/calabash-android:23:in `<main>'
```

I also checked my bash_profile for SDK it is perfectly fine as below

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/igate/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools"
```

Comment: Run it using the -v flag, and you can see exactly what fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as suggested on [Calabash installation docs](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/blob/master/documentation/installation.md#prerequisites) you should not use sudo neither when you install or when you use gems:

> You should never install gems with sudo. If you are having issues
>   installing bundler, we recommend using the Calabash Sandbox or using a
>   managed version of Ruby, e.g. rbenv or rvm.

In addition, coming back to Android SDK, make sure you download the right SDK from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-macosx.zip), unzip the file anywhere you want and insert into your .bash_profile the right paths.

For example, these are mines (I have unzipped folder into ~/Documents):

```
export ANDROID_HOME="$HOME/Documents/android-sdk-macosx"
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT="$ANDROID_HOME"
```

and it works like a charm